# Streaming over UDP

Tags: networking, video-streaming, vlc

I have to live stream video using VLC. The streaming is done over UDP. The problem is the computer receiving the stream is in a different network.
When I stream using the public IP of the receiver, it doesn't receive the stream. What should I do?

Comment: Is port forwarding required?

Comment: Define "a different network"

Comment: im streaming from a computer that is connected to my office's network.The reciever is at a network in my home

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment,

Yes, you need port forwarding. You stream to your home computer's public IP. However that IP is not you computer's; it is the IP address of the internet facing port of your router. Your router knows your computer by its local address (probably 192.168.x.x).

You need to do port forwarding to let your router know it needs to send incoming packets of a port, to a specific port of your computer. Router's web interface is likely to have such an option.